# How do I override a plugin registration in MVVMCross

Tags: wpf, sqlite, mvvmcross

I'm using the WPF Sqlite plugin in MVVMCross, but I want to override the directory that the database is written to. I've written a custom `ISQLiteConnectionFactory` which currently resides in my WPF bootstrapper project:

```
internal class CustomMvxWpfSqLiteConnectionFactory : ISQLiteConnectionFactory
{
    const string DirectoryName = "ProductName";

    public ISQLiteConnection Create(string address)
    {
        var appData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
        var dir = Path.Combine(appData, DirectoryName);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

        var path = Path.Combine(dir, address);
        return new SQLiteConnection(path, SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.Create, false);
    }
}
```

What I can't figure out is how to override the `Mvx.RegisterSingleton<ISQLiteConnectionFactory>(new MvxWpfSqLiteConnectionFactory());` that `Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.Wpf.Plugin` does.

My PCL project's `App` registers a singleton service that depends on `ISQLiteConnectionFactory` during Initialize, so I obviously want to override the IOC registration before then. But no matter what I do, the plugin's registration of `MvxWpfSqLiteConnectionFactory` rather than my own registration of `CustomMvxWpfSqLiteConnectionFactory` seems to take precedence.

I've tried putting my register call in all sorts of overrides in my WPF Setup.cs, but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An article on how plugins are loaded is included in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins#how-plugins-are-loaded

The Sqlite plugin by default is initialised during `PerformBootstrapActions` in Setup - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Customising-using-App-and-Setup#setupcs for where this occurs in the start sequence.

From your question, it's not clear which overrides in Setup you've tried - I'm not sure which positions "all sorts" includes. However, it sounds like want to register your `ISQLiteConnectionFactory` at any point after `PerformBootstrapActions` and before `InitializeApp` - so one way to do this would be to override `InitializeApp`:

```
protected virtual void InitializeApp(IMvxPluginManager pluginManager)
{
    // your code here
     base.InitializeApp(pluginManager);
}
```

Some possible other ideas to consider:

- if you want to prevent the Sqlite plugin from self-initializing in the Wpf case, then you could remove the Sqlite bootstrap file from your Wpf project (but beware that nuget might try to add it again later)
- the new "community fork" of the MvvmCross sqlite project has source code updated to the latest SQLite-net version (via @jarroda) and has a `BasePath` `CreateEx` option to allow the folder to be specified - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-SQLite/blob/master/Sqlite/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Community.Plugins.Sqlite.Wpf/MvxWpfSqLiteConnectionFactory.cs#L24